# Converting JavaScript `require` to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am reading a tutorial on Express and Node.js and trying to convert the JavaScript to TypeScript.

The code includes

```
var handlebars = require("express-handlebars")
    .create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });
```

which I have translated to TypeScript as is.

Is there a more idiomatic TypeScript using `import ... as` (from ECMAScript 6) or `import handlebars = ...` that accomplishes the same thing (including the call to `create`)?

I have tried the following:

```
import handlebars = require("express-handlebars")
handlebars.create({ defaultLayout: 'main' })
```

but I get a runtime error from nodejs on the later line

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine)
```

saying `Error: callback function required`.

I assume that the error comes because the object has not been properly created.

Comment: Try using the 'new' ES6 style syntax: `import * as handlebars from 'express-handlebars'`

Comment: I tried that, but when I add `handlebars.create(...)` as the next line, I get the nodejs error indicated above.

Comment: I do not know this package but looking at [the exports](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/index.js) there is no `engine` exported. I would guess it is `import * as handlebars from 'express-handlebars'; var engine = handlebars.create(...).engine; app.engine('handlebars, engine)`

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Converted the comment as an answer so that you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know this package but looking at [the exports](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/index.js) there is no `engine` exported.

My guess is

```
import * as handlebars from 'express-handlebars'; 
const engine = handlebars.create(...).engine; 
app.engine('handlebars', engine);
```